# Set base url for angular 2 http requests

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am trying to set base url for all my angular 2 http requests. Following is the basic set up for my application.

```js
class HttpOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  url:string = "http://10.7.18.21:8080/api/";
}


bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: HttpOptions})
]);


export class AppComponent {
  users:Array<User>
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    http.get("/users")
      .subscribe(res => this.users = res.json());
  }
}
```

The request is not sent to http://10.7.18.21:8080/api/users as I expected from my configuration. Instead the request is sent to http://localhost:8000/users.

**How do I set base url for http request in angular 2 application?**

I am using ***Angular 2.0.0-beta.0***.

Answer (score 55):

**For angular 4.3+ and @angular/common/http**

It's can be done with interceptors

```js
@Injectable()
export class ExampleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url = 'http://myurl.com';
    req = req.clone({
      url: url + req.url
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    AppComponent,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ExampleInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

EDIT: HttpClient and HttpInterceptor are introduced in Angular 4.3

Comment: NB: In order to avoid hard-coding the url in the interceptor, one may benefit from DI by doing something like this: `constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {}`

Answer (score 18):

UPDATE: See @vegazz answer for Angular 4.

For Angular 2.2.1, the following should prefix web api base url and represents a smaller footprint:

```js
import {Request, XHRBackend, XHRConnection} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {
    createConnection(request: Request): XHRConnection {
        if (request.url.startsWith('/')){
            request.url = 'http://localhost:3000' + request.url;     // prefix base url
        }
        return super.createConnection(request);
    }
}
```

Inject into providers in app.module.ts:

```js
providers: [
    { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: ApiXHRBackend }
  ]
```

Usage example:

```js
this._http.post('/api/my-route', {foo: 'bar'})
            .map<MyResponse>(res => res.json())
```

It seems to cover all methods (GET, PUT, POST, ...)

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way to deal with it. I made a slight change to your code and am using `localStrategy.getBaseHref()` so that I can set the `base href` in the HTML to `/dev` and the code will execute only then. In my case, I only needed this url `rewrite` for when I'm working locally.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I tested this in Angular 4.3.0 and it still works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work with angular 4 and HttpClientModule. But its simplier with interceptors. See answer below.

Comment: It still working in angular 6 but Just for HttpModule not for  HttpClientModule

Answer (score 11):

## For Angular2 Version 2.2 (As for Dec 2016)

Angular from RC5 mark `HTTP_PROVIDERS` as deprecated and trying to move things into `@NgModule`, the above solution is not really applicable, so as their documentation. I cross referred several other answers and found my way to implement base url, hope this might be helpful to someone else.

The basic idea is, instead of doing things in bootstrap, we move things to `AppModule`.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


import { CustomRequestOptions } from './customrequest.options';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptions }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

And move CustomRequestOptions into a separate injectable service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = 'http://localhost:9080' + options.url;
    return super.merge(options);
  }
}
```

#### Edit for request method other than GET.

If you are trying to send request type other than GET, the previous method fails to inject the baseurl into the request. This is because Angular2 generate new `RequestOptions` other than `this._defaultOptions` whose merge method isn't being override by our CustomRequestOptions. (See the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.0/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L39-L183) here).

So instead of returning `super.merge(...)` in the last step of CustomRequestOptions merge method, I generated a new instance of `CustomRequestOptions` to ensure the following operation will still work.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
  merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
    if (options !== null && options.url !== null) {
      options.url = 'http://localhost:9080' + options.url;
    }
    let requestOptions = super.merge(options)
    return new CustomRequestOptions({
      method: requestOptions.method,
      url: requestOptions.url,
      search: requestOptions.search,
      headers: requestOptions.headers,
      body: requestOptions.body,
      withCredentials: requestOptions.withCredentials,
      responseType: requestOptions.responseType
    });
  }
}
```

And this works for POST, PUT, DELETE method as well. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: im getting an error: 
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomRequestOptions: (?). at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor]... any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Angular you are running on? I found this [new issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13609) on github and I wonder if it is related to the version.

Comment: @angular/core@^2.3.1, i will see what i can get from that link that you posted. ta

Comment: @sawe Any luck with your research? I'm using angular@2.4.5 and angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26.

Comment: ended up creating my own HttpClient, that simply makes use of the angular http and adds the headers etc as well, in addition to using my prefered api url:

Comment: @sawe Care to share your implementation? The above solution works but if I make use of AOT compilation it breaks with : Property 'RequestOptionsArgs' does not exist on type 'typeof ".../node_modules/@angular/http/src/interfaces"'.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/57APx3tOovFDJLjLpbfo I have added some of the relevant files (4 in total),

Answer (score 7):

Different approach: during development running your app in localhost, consider configuring a *proxy* instead.

proxy.conf.json

```js
{
   "/api/**": {
      "target": "http://10.7.18.21:8080/",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
   }
}
```

More: [link](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/)

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more. All of the solutions above are just simply overengineered just for one little prefix.

Comment: remember to start the server with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open`

Comment: Thats fine for ng serve but it doesn't work for production as it's not an option for ng build

Comment: Indeed, this approach assumes that the Angular application will be deployed to the same backend target, so you do not proxy your requests in production.

Comment: However it is perfectly fine if your angular application is available at http://10.7.18.21:8080/ while http://10.7.18.21:8080/api is be the backend for it.

Answer (score 6):

In **Angular 2.0.0-beta.6** You can achieve this by overriding 'merge'

```js
import {BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs} from 'angular2/http';

export class ApRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

  merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = 'http://10.7.18.21:8080/api' + options.url;
    return super.merge(options);
  }

}
```

Comment: Just found out that it is working for `GET` and `DELETE` but not for `POST` and `PUT`. :/

Comment: As @TheKojuEffect mentioned this solution doesn't work with some methods using more elegant API. However if you choose to use more verbose one: _http.request(..)_ it seems to work.

Comment: actually, I found it not so easy to implement this, as super.merge actually returns a `RequestOptions` instance which, in case of [Http#post](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts#L131) a new `RequestOptions` instance is created before merging with the old one. Long story short, I really had to override merge and return a custom instance like this: https://gist.github.com/rweng/1d36dd91842f3cb58ebb

Comment: It doesn't works for **http.post** and **http.put** , but it works for **http.request** , so you can have something like :

**this.http.request('/user/1', {
            body: body,
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: headers
        })**

Answer (score 5):

After having a look at code sources for `BaseRequestOptions`, `RequestOptions` and `Http` classes:

- [base_request_options.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/base_request_options.ts)
- [http.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts)

It appears that the `url` property corresponds to the default URL but not a prefix for URLs.

To implement your use case, I would suggest to put a service in front of the http object and inject then the service. Something like that:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  http: Http;
  urlPrefix: string;

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.urlPrefix = 'http://...';
  }

  get(url) {
    return this.http.get(this.urlPrefix + url);
  }

  post(url, data) {
    return this.http.post(this.urlPrefix + url, data);
  }
}
```

And

```js
import {HttpClient} from './http-client';

export classMyComponent {
  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  handleSomething() {
    this.httpClient.post(url, data)
    ).subscribe(...);
  }
}
```

That said such could perhaps be contributed to Angular2 itself ;-)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: How I will handle the query string appended in my url.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import {LocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

constructor(private locationStrategy:LocationStrategy) {
  console.log(locationStrategy.prepareExternalUrl('xxx'));
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1bec4f6c6135d7aaccec7492d70c36e1ceeaeefa/modules/angular2/test/router/path_location_strategy_spec.ts#L88

Answer (score 0):

For currently user, here is really working example in **angular 2.4.8**

[here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L39-L183) is the code for why split and chained **BaseCommonRequestOptions** and **CommonRequestOptions**.

```js
import { BaseRequestOptions, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BaseCommonRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

  merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
    return new CommonRequestOptions(super.merge(extracted(options)));
  }
}

/**
 * for inner merge when using post put patch delete...others method
 */
export class CommonRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
  merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
    return new RequestOptions(super.merge(extracted(options)));
  }
}

/**
 * inject default values
 *
 * @param options
 * @returns {RequestOptionsArgs}
 */
export function extracted(options: RequestOptionsArgs) {
  console.log(options);
  if (!validUrl(options.url)) {
    options.url = 'http://localhost:3000' + (options.url ? options.url : "");
  }
  // use default header application/json, if content-type header was empty.
  if (options.headers != null) {
    let contentType = options.headers.get('content-type');
    if (contentType == null || contentType == '') {
      options.headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    }
  } else {
    options.headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
  }

  return options;
}

/**
 * validate url
 *
 * @param url
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
export function validUrl(url: string) {
  return /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a .ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Request, XHRBackend, XHRConnection} from '@angular/http';


    @Injectable()
    export class ApiXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {
    createConnection(request: Request): XHRConnection {
    if (request.url.startsWith('/api')){
    var url=request.url.replace("/api", "");
    request.url = 'http://localhost:8080' + url; // prefix base url
    }
    return super.createConnection(request);
    }

}
```

Then in app.module.ts

```
import { ApiXHRBackend } from './guard/httpintercepter';
import {Request, XHRBackend, XHRConnection} from '@angular/http';
```

Add provider in providers section

```
providers: [
{provide: XHRBackend, useClass: ApiXHRBackend }
],
```

then in your service.ts http call must be like below example

```
return this._http.post("/api/customerservice/loginvalidation",data)
.map((response: Response) => {
return response;
});
```

Here /api will be replaced by your base URL http://localhost:8080

more details 
http://shabeen.in/webschool/how-to-set-angular-2-service-http-base-url/