# Angular2 base url how to reference it?

Tags: typescript, angular

I come across this post [Angular 2 dynamically change base url in post requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687038/angular-2-dynamically-change-base-url-in-post-requests).

In my component, if I do instantiate a new instance of CustomRequestOptions

```
      let options = new CustomRequestOptions();
```

options.url is empty.

My question is how do I get the base url out of CustomRequestOptions in my components?