# Appending some info to each requset in REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-boot, restangular

I have an angular application. From frontend I can set some value. This value is something like config, which can be changed.
It is simple string variable.  How to attach this config to each REST request ?
I ask mainly about approach.

Maybe pass it via headers is good idea ?

Comment: What do you want to do with those values, in server side?

Answer (score 0):

For angular 1.x, write an [Interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests

For angular 2.x / 4.x, [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions) should be the key to solve your problem. [Set base url for angular 2 http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516651/set-base-url-for-angular-2-http-requests)

I'm using angular2, my solution is create a `Service` and inject "Http" dependency, then write two methods "get", "post", these methods add an entry to header before calling "Http", in other component / service, I just inject this `Service` class, then call its "get" or "post".

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be somewhat like this  If your working in angular 1.3 or less
The data should be sent as **body** data to **server**

```
var basecall = Restangular.all('url');
bascall.post($scope.config).then(function(data){

 })
```